# How to mark an option element as selected, if I use choices with objects?

Tags: php, symfony

I am using Symfony 3 framework.

Next code is from my src/AppBundle/Form/ArticleType.php file:

```
class ArticleType extends AbstractType
{    
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder->add('title')
                ->add('publishAt', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'choices' => array(
                    'now' => new \DateTime('now'),
                    'tomorrow' => new \DateTime('+1 day'),
                    '1 week' => new \DateTime('+1 week'),
                    '1 month' => new \DateTime('+1 month')
                ),
                'data' => 2,
                ));
        }
...
}
```

The code generates a form with next select element:

```
<select ...>
  <option value="0">now</option>
  <option value="1">tomorrow</option>
  <option value="2">1 week</option>
  <option value="3">1 month</option>
</select>
```

I want to have the option with value="2" as selected.

This works:

```
->add('publishAt', ChoiceType::class, array(
    'choices' => array(
       'now' => 0,
       'tomorrow' => 1,
       '1 week' => 2,
       '1 month' => 3,
     ),
     'data' => 2,
    )
);
```

But I have objects instead of numbers. How can I resolve it?

Comment: please post code with objects

Comment: The objects are new \DateTime('...') above.

Comment: Does this work? `'data' => '1 week'`

Comment: Neither 'data' => '1 week' nor 'data' => new \DateTime('+1 week') works.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the selected value depends on the data you are manipulating on the form but you can specify the value for when the value is empty.

```
->add('publishAt', ChoiceType::class, array(
    'choices' => array(
       'now' => 0,
       'tomorrow' => 1,
       '1 week' => 2,
       '1 month' => 3,
     ),
     'empty_data' => '1 week',
    )
);
```

Empty data: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#empty-data

Although when you build the form you set the data that will overwrite the empty_data option.

```
    $task = new Task();
    $task->setTask('Write a blog post');
    $task->setDueDate(new \DateTime('tomorrow'));

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
        ->add('task', TextType::class)
        ->add('dueDate', DateType::class)
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Create Post'))
        ->getForm();

    return $this->render('default/new.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
```

Full documented example: http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#building-the-form